# Python group by part of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm looking at names of files and some of them have _good and _new suffix at the end. I need to move these files but when I come across a file that has two versions, _good and _new, I only wan the _new files to move.

Here's an example of file names:

```
student_homework_good
student_homework_new
house_work_good
school_work_good
commute_good
```

From these files, I don't want `student_homework_good` to move because student_new exists.
The file names are stored in a list: my_files[]

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: My suggestion would be to give this a crack and [edit] the question with a [mre] of your code and where you are running into an issue.

Comment: @fafz what you mean when you are saying **move**, also where you want to move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty easy. All you need to do, is to check the existence of `_new` in file name, like

```py
listOfFiles = ['student_homework_new', 'student_homework_good', 'commute_good']
for i in listOfFiles:
    if '_new' in i:
        # code for movement to another directory
```

Any other `_good` files will remain in the same directory.

If you only want to group them by names, you could do something like

```py
goodFiles = [i for i in os.listdir('yourdirectory') if '_good' in i]
newFiles  = [i for i in os.listdir('yourdirectory') if '_new' in i]
```

After grouping, you can move whatever you want to any folder of course.

Comment: Thank you, I set up the loop the way you suggested and I'm able to select just the new files when there are two versions.